# gdalwarp without reading the whole file, just coordinates

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdalinfo

I'm working with a multiple remotely hosted, large files.
I want to apply `gdalwarp` on them all, but I don't need the raster data; just the new corner coordinates.

Is there a way to use `gdalwarp` without having to read in the whole file?

I just need the part that `gdalinfo` outputs as "Corner Coordinates".

Comment: Just to make sure, do you want to get the corner coordinates of the new image as here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49020/rotating-a-rectangle? Thus the corners of the new bounding box. That's also what gdalinfo reports. Sometimes people think that the new coordinates express the locations of the original corner points after warping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to a VRT ([GDAL Virtual format](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html))

```
gdalwarp args etc. infile outfile.vrt
```